# postgresql WHERE x = y OR x IN (1,2,3) if y = ''

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, where-clause

Is it possible to create a WHERE CLAUSE like this :

```
SELECT * FROM something WHERE (x = y OR x IN (1,2,3) if y = '')
```

What would be the correct SQL syntax ?

Comment: Are you looking at y = '' where a) y is empty string or where b) y is undefined (i.e. NULL)? Is it 1) (x = y) OR (x in (1,2,3) if y = '') , 2)  (x = y OR x in (1,2,3)) if y = '')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain boolean expressions in SQL, ie:

```
SELECT * FROM something WHERE ((x = y) OR (x IN (1,2,3) AND y = ''))
```

Comment: It's working fine when y is different from ' ', the WHERE clause uses x = y. But it's not working when y = ' ', it seems the WHERE clause does not use the x IN (1,2,3) as no line come up in results

Comment: Could it be that `y` is not really an empty string, but NULL?

Comment: I have this : SELECT * FROM something WHERE ((os.name IN (SELECT name_fr FROM order_status WHERE id IN (2,4,6,7,8,12,13)) AND '' = '') OR (os.name_fr = ''))

Comment: Not sure what was meant by AND '' = ''?